# How to save the model while training and resume later in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am using sklearn GridSearchCV to find the best parameters for my model.

It's taking too long to fit. Is there way we can save the model while fitting and resume later.

I know we can use pickle to save a trained model. I am looking for a way to save the model while fitting using GridSearchCV and resume from the saved status later.

Thanks

Comment: `save_weights`?

Comment: No you cant do that. What you can do however is to divide your parameter space so that you can train on small parameter space at a time. Save the results. Train the others at later time and combine the results. Make sure to set the random_state to reproduce the process.